# Select rows with Max(Column Value) for each unique combination of two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working with a sample table like below. A Dataset has multiple groups, and each time a write to the table occurs, the RunNumber increments for the dataset, along with data for each group and the total. Each Dataset/Group combo will usually have multiple rows, example below:

| RunNumber | Group | Dataset | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 | Dataset A | 10 |
| 1 | Group1 | Dataset A | 20 |
| 2 | Group1 | Dataset A | 30 |
| 2 | Group2 | Dataset A | 15 |
| 1 | Group1 | Dataset B | 5 |
| 1 | Group2 | Dataset B | 10 |
| 1 | Group3 | Dataset A | 30 |
| 2 | Group3 | Dataset A | 30 |
| 1 | Group1 | Dataset C | 15 |
| 1 | Group2 | Dataset C | 50 |
| 2 | Group2 | Dataset C | 70 |
| 2 | Group2 | Dataset C | 90 |

What I want to do is essential for each combination of Dataset and Group, return all data for rows that have the max(RunNumber) for the given Dataset/Group combination. So for example, the above sample would return this:

| RunNumber | Group | Dataset | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Group1 | Dataset A | 30 |
| 2 | Group2 | Dataset A | 15 |
| 1 | Group1 | Dataset B | 5 |
| 1 | Group2 | Dataset B | 10 |
| 2 | Group3 | Dataset A | 30 |
| 1 | Group1 | Dataset C | 15 |
| 2 | Group2 | Dataset C | 70 |
| 2 | Group2 | Dataset C | 90 |

Where the Dataset/Groups match, all rows are kept with the max RunNumber for that given combo.
For now, I've split this into 2 separate queries, where i first query for the max(RunNumber) for all distinct Dataset/Group combos, then do a select * for all matches. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh using 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL 5.x you can use a sub-query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE (`Group`, Dataset, RunNumber) IN (
    SELECT `Group`, Dataset, MAX(RunNumber) AS MaxRunNumber
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY `Group`, Dataset
  );
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a1381ea2fb11109a675527eac733f42b)*

**Alternatives**

```
--
-- LEFT JOIN on bigger
--
SELECT t.* 
FROM your_table t
LEFT JOIN your_table t2
  ON t2.`Group` = t.`Group`
 AND t2.Dataset = t.Dataset
 AND t2.RunNumber > t.RunNumber
WHERE t2.RunNumber IS NULL
ORDER BY t.`Group`, t.Dataset;

--
-- where NOT EXISTS on bigger
--
SELECT * 
FROM your_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM your_table t2
  WHERE t2.`Group` = t.`Group`
    AND t2.Dataset = t.Dataset
    AND t2.RunNumber > t.RunNumber
)
ORDER BY `Group`, Dataset;

--
-- Emulating DENSE_RANK = 1 with variables
-- Works also in 5.x
--
SELECT RunNumber, `Group`, Dataset, Total
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    @rnk:=IF(@ds=Dataset AND @grp=`Group`, IF(@run=RunNumber, @rnk, @rnk+1), 1) AS Rnk
  , @grp := `Group` as `Group`
  , @ds := Dataset as Dataset
  , @run := RunNumber as RunNumber
  , Total
  FROM your_table t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp:=null, @ds:=null, @run:=null, @rnk := 0) var
  ORDER BY `Group`, Dataset, RunNumber DESC
) q
WHERE Rnk = 1
ORDER BY `Group`, Dataset;

--
-- DENSE_RANK = 1
-- MySql 8 and beyond. 
--
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `Group`, Dataset ORDER BY RunNumber DESC) AS rnk
  FROM your_table
) q
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY `Group`, Dataset;
```

Comment: thanks! out of curiosity, how could i go about this without using a sub-query?

Comment: @javarookie I've included some alternatives.

Comment: you're a legend @LukStorms